# Setting ScrollView contentSize in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, scrollview

Is it possible to explicitly set content size of ScrollView in SwiftUI (like we do in UIKit)? I tried setting frame or height of ScrollView to 10000 points but it seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

ScrollView automatically has contentSize equal to all its child view's sizes. So you can simply add a `Spacer` and set a frame for it. Changing the scrollView frame by itself won't have any effect unless you put scrollView inside another View.

```swift
ScrollView {
    Spacer()
        .frame(height: 1000)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    ...
}
```